# Name for pouring water oscillations?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, everyday-life, terminology

When you pour a container of water but then it starts to push against itself and then starts pouring in pulses, what is that phenomena called and is there a way to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the water pours out of the container, air has to enter in the same amount. The water leaving shares the same opening with the air trying to get in, and they take turns. This is a certain type of *two-phase flow*. You can eliminate it by providing a second opening in the container for the air to flow in through while the water is leaving through the first opening.

Comment: When you say same amount do you mean the same volume or the same mass or at the same velocity or...

Comment: same volume. -NN